# Word Macro to open Excel file, Copy Excel table, and Paste table at end of Word Document

Tags: ms-word, copy-paste

I'm looking for a macro that opens the File Dialog, allows a user to select their table (table are all the same size), and then automatically pastes that table at the end of their Word Document.

I'm okay at editing VBA code but not very good at creating it. Most of this is pulled from random samples I've found here. I am getting an error at:

Set oExcelWorkBook = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open (fileName)

Here is the full code I'm using:

```
Sub MakeTablefromExcelFile()
'advanced
Dim oExcelApp, oExcelWorkbook, oExcelWorksheet, oExcelRange
Dim nNumOfRows As Long
Dim nNumOfCols As Long
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, oExcelWorksheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    
Dim oTable As Table    'word table
Dim oRow As Row    'word row
Dim oCell As Cell    'word table cell
Dim x As Long, y As Long    'counter for loops


Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select your publishing table"
    .Filters.Clear
            
    If .Show = True Then
    fileName = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
    
    End If
End With
    
Set oExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcelApp.Visible = True
Set oExcelWorkbook = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)    'open workbook and asign it to variable
Set oExcelWorksheet = oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets(1)    'asign first worksheet to variable
Set oExcelRange = oExcelWorksheet.Range("A1:F31")
nNumOfRows = oExcelRange.Rows.Count
nNumOfCols = oExcelRange.Columns.Count

ActiveDocument.Range.InsertParagraphAfter    'just makes new paragraph at the end of doc, Table will be created here
Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range, NumRows:=nNumOfRows, NumColumns:=nNumOfCols)    'create table and asign it to variable
'***real deal, table gets filled here
For x = 1 To nNumOfRows
    For y = 1 To nNumOfCols
        oTable.Cell(x, y).Range.Text = oExcelRange.Cells(x, y).Value
    Next y
Next x
'***
oExcelWorkbook.Close False
oExcelApp.Quit
With oTable
    .Range.Font.Size = 9
    .Columns(1).Width = 225
    .Columns(2).Width = 75
    .Columns(3).Width = 60
    .Columns(4).Width = 60
    .Columns(5).Width = 60
    .Columns(6).Width = 60
    .Rows.Height = 20
End With
```

End Sub
'''

Thanks for your help

Comment: I found a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that fixed most issues I was having. I'm still getting a minor issue with counting columns in VBA for Word though

```
Sub MakeTablefromExcelFile()
'
Dim oExcelApp, oExcelWorkbook, oExcelWorksheet, oExcelRange
Dim nNumberOfRows As Integer
Dim nNumberOfCols As Integer
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, fileFolder As String, total As 
Integer
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

Dim oTable As Table    'word table
Dim oRow As Row    'word row
Dim oCell As Cell    'word table cell
Dim x As Long, y As Long    'counter for loops

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewThumbnail
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select your publishing table"
    .InitialFileName = fileFolder
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewThumbnail
    .Filters.Clear
    
If .Show = True Then
    fileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    
End If
End With

Set oExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcelApp.Visible = True
Set oExcelWorkbook = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
Set oExcelWorksheet = oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets(1)    'asign first worksheet to variabl
Set oExcelRange = oExcelWorksheet.Range("A1:F31")
nNumberOfRows = oExcelRange.Rows.Count
nNumberOfCols = oExcelRange.Columns.Count

ActiveDocument.Range.InsertParagraphAfter    'just makes new paragraph at the end of doc, Table will be created here
Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range, NumRows:=nNumberOfRows, NumColumns:=nNubmerOfCols)    'create table and asign it to variable
'***real deal, table gets filled here
For x = 1 To nNumberOfRows
For y = 1 To nNumberOfCols
    oTable.Cell(x, y).Range.Text = oExcelRange.Cells(x, y).Value
Next y
Next x
'***
oExcelWorkbook.Close False
oExcelApp.Quit

With oTable
.Range.Font.Size = 9
.AutoFitBehavior _
    wdAutoFitWindow

End With

End Sub
```